# Python Tkinter, simple example fails on win 7

Tags: python, windows-7, tkinter

From [here](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/minimal-app.html) I've copied an example of python gui app, but it's not working.
It starts up and show window, but when i click the Quit button it just freze. And if I run it again then i got another quit button in previous window.

Is there error in example code or is this problem with win 7 ? 
I am using python 2.6.5 and win 7 32 bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the button is clicked, it tries to call `self.quit`, which doesn't exist.
Try adding this method to the `Application` class.

```
....
    def quit(self):
        import sys
        sys.exit()
....
```

Answer (score 3):

```
def quit(self):
    self.master.destroy()
```

works too.